# Ubuntu 14.04 git https serving with nginx problem

Tags: git, ubuntu, nginx, https, fastcgi

I have my `https://git.example.com/` site to serve static files working well on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/git.example.com` config is like this:

```
location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location ~ (/.*) {
        client_max_body_size 0; # Git pushes can be massive, just to make sure nginx doesn't suddenly cut the connection add this.
        auth_basic "Git Login"; # Whatever text will do.
        auth_basic_user_file "/var/www/git_htpasswd";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; # Include the default fastcgi configs
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend; # Tells fastcgi to pass the request to the git http backend executable
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/repo;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1; # Takes the capture group from our location directive and gives git that.
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
}
```

(The site config file is linked to `sites-enabled`.)

The unix socket `var/run/fcgiwrap.socket` is there.
The `/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend` program is there.

I access the repo using the following URL:

`https://git.example.com/info.git`

`git remote show orig`

ERROR:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.example.com/info.git/': The requested URL returned error: 502
```

And on server site at `/var/log/nginx`:

`cat error.log`

```
2018/12/15 23:38:15 [error] 26794#0: *8 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 223.167.127.110, server: git.example.com, request: "GET /info.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1", host: "git.example.com"
2018/12/15 23:38:16 [error] 26794#0: *8 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Cannot execute script (/var/www/repo/info.git/info/refs)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 223.167.xxx.xxx, server: git.example.com, request: "GET /info.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "git.example.com"
```

It looks like `/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend` is not run at all.
I tried replace this program with a test script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$@" >/tmp/backend.log
set >> /tmp/backend.log
```

And run some `git remote show origin` command from client side, nothing appeared at `/tmp` (no `backend.log` file)

What's wrong with my setup?
Thanks.

Comment: `git.dabaober.com` -> `git.example.com`, no? :-)

Comment: Forgot to hide my domain in the terminal copy & paste... Question updated...

Comment: There are still more mentions…